# Iterate over a list and save values

Tags: python, c++, list, dictionary, scheduled-tasks

Im trying to do that but i cant.

I have a variable that gives me values, and i want something like that:

```
value = 1

x[0] = 1
x[1] = 0
x[2] = 0


-------

value 7

x[0] = 1
x[1] = 7
x[2] = 0
```

and the list is continuously filled,
and when it fills up, it would come back and exchange the value for the first position and so on.

I'm a recent programmer, I tried several ways and I couldn't

Comment: you need to append the data in a file and keep track of value

Comment: Please show us one of your attempts.  It's also not clear from where the variable should get filled.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a *circular array*.  To maintain this, just keep track of how many items you stored in it, and maintain a tail index so you know where to add the next value.

```
const int N = 3;
int x[N];
int tail = 0, size = 0;

// To add values:
for(int value; std::cin >> value; ) {
    x[tail] = value;
    tail = (tail + 1) % N;
    if (size < N) ++size;
}

// To print the array from the oldest item:
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    std::cout << x[(i + tail) % N] << "\n";
}
```